# How to add UIView as child to SKNode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

As I have found out there is no easy way to add UIViews as children to SKNodes.
I know there is a scene method didMoveToView, but I would like to make a custom text box, and I want to encapsulate all code about it there.
I have a separate class for TextBox (from SKNode), and it creates background and layouts itself, but as I found out SKLabelNode does not support multiline text and I need that.
I'm left with option showing my text box and separate UILabel over it in scene, but this breaks all incapsulation.

What options are available to me if I want to have custom text box made of SKNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious option is placing `UILabel` above your `SKView`. You can also synchronize frame with some `SKNode` to be able to move the label using node manipulation.

Comment: Can you explain both sentences in more detail?  I do see this was 4 years ago.  But it still seems applicable.

Comment: @Neo42 You create a `UILabel`, add it as subview or sibling to `SKView`, then you configure its properties to look just like the `SKNode` you want to _fake_, for example `label.frame = node.frame;`. This is a common trick in graphic editors that use OpenGL for rendering and allow double-clicking text layers for text editing.